# PLACEHOLDER - DraftWriter

Tags: script, placeholder

The script is designed to create a draft of a Stack Overflow question.
The main components of this application are:

- Stack Overflow API: The application interacts with the Stack Overflow API to perform the required operations, such as posting the draft question and redirecting the user to verify it. The user's API key and access token are used to authenticate and authorize the application to perform these actions on the user's behalf.
- OAuth2 workflow: The application uses the implicit OAuth2 workflow to acquire an access token for the user, allowing the app to perform write operations on their behalf.

The script is under development and may be published when the safety and ethics aspects of the automating script is verified.